# ListView CustomAdapter not showing first position results

Tags: java, android, listview, custom-adapter

I'm new to Android Studio and coding in general and I am trying to display a custom ListView with an image of a colour and the name of the colour. I have used a custom Adapter to inflate the view with two arrays containing the drawable image colours and string of the names.

The problem I am having - the custom adapter is only displaying the layers from position 1 and onwards. For example, where the first layer should be img_01 and "red" - it is displaying img_02 and "Orange".

I've tried debugging the code and it seems that though the adapter is setting the values for position 0, but I cannot find the reason why it is not displaying (as the others are displaying fine).

The images & names are just placeholders, so an alternative solution that doesn't include both the drawables and names wouldn't be viable,

Thank you in advance

CustomAdapter.java

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    Context context;
    int[] images;
    String[] colour;
    LayoutInflater mInflater;

    public CustomAdapter(Context c, int[] i, String[] col) {
        this.context = c; //sets the application context that has been passed to the adapter
        this.images = i; //sets the images array that has been passed to the adapter
        this.colour = col; //sets the colour array that has been passed to the adapter
        mInflater = (LayoutInflater.from(context)); //sets the layout inflater from context
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() { //total number of elements in the array
        return images.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) { //gets the item using the position
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) { //gets the item position
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) { //this is used to update the view

        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_layout, null);

        ImageView image = convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);

        TextView text = convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView);

        text.setText(colour[position]);
        image.setImageResource(images[position]);
        return convertView;

    }
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ListView mListView;

    int[] images = {R.drawable.img01,
    R.drawable.img02,
    R.drawable.img03,
    R.drawable.img04};

    String[] colour = {"Red",
    "Orange",
    "Yellow",
    "Green"};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mListView = findViewById(R.id.listView);

        CustomAdapter customAdapter = new CustomAdapter(getApplicationContext(), images, colour);
        //passes information of images and application context to the item adapter
        mListView.setAdapter(customAdapter);
        //sets the adapter to the listview

    }
}
```

custom_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="7dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="9dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/img01" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="99dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="99dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
        android:text="colourName" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="409dp"
        android:layout_height="729dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to set the height of the `ListView` to `wrap_content` instead of hardcoding it

```
<ListView
    ...
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with RecyclerView.

1. Create a custom class

```
public class ExampleItem {
    private int mImageResource; //your color image
    private String mText1; //your text

    public ExampleItem(int imageResource, String text1) {
        mImageResource = imageResource;
        mText1 = text1;
    }
    public int getImageResource() {
        return mImageResource;
    }
    public String getText1() {
        return mText1;
    }
}
```

2. Create a XML layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="4dp">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="4dp">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:padding="2dp" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView"
            android:text="Line 1"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

3. Create a Recycler View Adapter

```
public class ExampleAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ExampleAdapter.ExampleViewHolder> {
    private ArrayList<ExampleItem> mExampleList;
    public static class ExampleViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public ImageView mImageView;
        public TextView mTextView1;

        public ExampleViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            mTextView1 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        }
    }
    public ExampleAdapter(ArrayList<ExampleItem> exampleList) {
        mExampleList = exampleList;
    }
    @Override
    public ExampleViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.example_item, parent, false);
        ExampleViewHolder evh = new ExampleViewHolder(v);
        return evh;
    }
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ExampleViewHolder holder, int position) {
        ExampleItem currentItem = mExampleList.get(position);
        holder.mImageView.setImageResource(currentItem.getImageResource());
        holder.mTextView1.setText(currentItem.getText1());
    }
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mExampleList.size();
    }
}
```

4. your activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.application.recyclerviewproject.MainActivity">
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

5. MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ArrayList<ExampleItem> exampleList = new ArrayList<>();
        exampleList.add(new ExampleItem(R.drawable.img01, "Red"));
        exampleList.add(new ExampleItem(R.drawable.img02, "Orange"));
        exampleList.add(new ExampleItem(R.drawable.img03, "Yellow"));
        exampleList.add(new ExampleItem(R.drawable.img04, "Green"));

        mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        mAdapter = new ExampleAdapter(exampleList);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    }
}
```